# Xcode does not show iOS 12.5 Simulator

Tags: ios, version, ios-simulator, xcode12, ios12

I can not find **iOS 12.5** version for **Simulator** from (Xcode -> Preferences -> Components).

[image]

I checked it on Xcode versions 12.2 and 12.4 without any success. Does anyone know why?, Do I need to perform any update?, the latest iOS version Xcode shows in Components section is **14.3**

Comment: Hey @Joule87, did you find out how to get 12.5 installed? Cheers.